# Objective-C class instance zeroed at alloc?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, initialization

Is there any kind of memory-zeroing objective-c undertakes on my behalf when I first allocate a class instance? I see a lot of objective-c code out there that presumes their outlets are `nil` by default. If I do the same am I basing such behavior on false pretenses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSAllocateObject` returns a block of memory large enough to include all the ivars in the class; its `isa` pointer is set to the class, and the rest of the block is filled with 0. `+[NSObject alloc]` calls `+[NSObject allocWithZone:]` which then calls `NSAllocateObject` internally.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, all alloced objects are zeroed out. See [NSObject alloc documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc). It is guaranteed by the language so it is perfectly safe to do so and in fact setting the members to 0 yourself would be redundant.