# How does an uninitiliazed variable get a garbage value?

Tags: c, variables, compiler-construction, programming-languages, initialization

When we create a variable and don't initialize it, then some (random) number called *garbage value* is assigned to it.

- How this value is assigned to the variable?
- What is whole concept/mechanism behind this?
- Does this happen only in C?

Comment: I would be the last to condemn homework-type questions, but isn't this a bit _too_ obvious?

Comment: @DrJokepu   If it would have been obvious to me, I wouldn't waste my time on it.

Comment: @Ravi, the answer is of course not obvious. What I meant, this looks like a set of questions from a school assignment to me. That's because the questions are constructed in a way that makes the impression that the original asker knew the answers to his or her questions.

Comment: @ DrJokepu  Oh!I misunderstood it.Still, ignore the style of the question.I definitely didn't ask that question to test people's knowledge.I really don't know about it.

Comment: @DrJokepu - I got the opposite impression "who and how does it?" screams to me a "wrong question", asked by someone who genuinely doesn't know what's going on, since it has no answer.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The garbage value is not *assigned*, rather the value is already there. When you allocate a variable you are reserving a piece of memory - until you overwrite it that memory will contain whatever "random" information was there before.

As a metaphor, think of allocating a variable like buying a piece of land - until you do something with it (like build a house) the land will just have whatever trash was already sitting there (like an old crumbling house).

Some languages will automatically fill newly allocated variables with zeros - this takes time to do. In more "do-it-yourself" languages like C this extra behavoir is not guarenteed (though on some systems memory is cleared regardless of language, for example as a security measure)

Comment: Ah! Well put than mine :). Great! +1

Comment: For example, MSVC initializes everything to 0xcccccccc in debug mode (which can come quite helpful sometimes)

Comment: I'm trying to think of the name of the debugger (late 90s IIRC) that used 0xf00d to fill newly allocated memory...any help?

Comment: @pm100 The letter `o` is not a digit in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 6):

Memory is used and reused at various points in your application. For example, as the call stack of your application grows and shrinks the same location in memory may be overwritten many, many times. The thing to remember is that as a piece of memory is abandoned it is not zeroed out, so if you do not specify a new initial value for that place in memory when you use it again you will get the old, "garbage" value.

Some [languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317626/objective-c-class-instance-zeroed-at-alloc) and [structure implementations](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/) do default-initialize memory as it is used. Others do not, so it is important to read the documentation of your language carefully to know what to expect.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody explicitly assigns a grabage value. If you create a variable, only location of the variable is determined, and not its value. Thats why we are initializing it. The garbage value might come from some previous operations over the same memory by old processes! So it can hold anything. I think it holds to pretty good number of languages. I am not sure about the list! :)

Answer (score 2):

When we create a variable and don't initialize it, then nothing happens. When you read value from that variable you get data from memory where variable located now. It could looks like garbage/random value only because variables [are placed in memory with some degree of randomness.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232081/heap-randomization-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

C standards say:

- undefined behavior for local variables: [(Why) is using an uninitialized variable undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c) (e.g. segfault is legal)
- zero for global variables: [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value)

Implementation: detailed examination of an implementation at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36725211/895245 Summary:

- local: the address is never written to, so whatever was there previously gets used
- global: `.bss`