# for loop will perform only one loop

Tags: c, for-loop, initialization

I need to make a C program to read the number of students(`1<=students<=25`) in a class and for every student to read his exam score ex `10/20` `15/20` etc(`1<=score<=20`) and print the max and the max score of students and the average score of class.

I made the program but it performs the `for` loop only once for some reason.

Can you please help me understand why?

here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int m,i,b,sum,min,max,mo;
    sum=0;
    while (m<1 || m>25) {
            printf("give number of students ");
            scanf("%d",&m);
    }
    for (i=1; i<(m+1); i++) {
            while (b<1 || b>20) {
            printf("give score of  %d student",i);
            scanf("%d",&b);
            }

            if(i==1) {
                    min=b;
                    max=b;
            }
            else {
                    if(b<min) min=b;
                    if(b>max) max=b;
            }
            sum=sum+b;
    }
    mo=sum/m;
    printf("max is  %d and min is  %d and avg is  %d",max,min,mo);
}
```

Comment: You're missing a format specifier in your output.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you compile this program? Have you tried to fix them?

Comment: You don't initialize `m`, so its value is *indeterminate*, i.e., it could be anything.  You then proceed to check if it is less than 1 or greater than 25. Of course, at that point, it may or may not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - initialize your variables:

```
int m,i,b,sum,min,max,mo; // these are declared and uninitialized

m = 0;  // now it's initialized to 0
i = 0;
...
```

If you don't initialize them to something, you don't know what they are to start with.

Second - You need to change the value of `b`:

```
for (i=1; i<(m+1); i++) {
        while (b<1 || b>20) {  <-- here you're checking for b being valid
        printf("give score of %d student",i);
        scanf("%d",&b);
        }
```

So the first time in b will be between 1 and 20, if you don't reset it to something invalid you'll never get here again. After you record the value of b:

```
    sum=sum+b;
    b = 0;   // we're done with b for now, set it to something invalid for the while()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not initialized the `m` and using in `while` condition

It is `undefined behaviour` using uninitialized local variable in conditon

Want to implement the same

use

```
do
{
  printf("give number of students ");
            scanf("%d",&m);
}
while(m<1 || m>25);
```

`for (i=1; i<(m+1); i++)` change the condition as `i<=m` It's the good technique rather `<` and then adding `1`
Inside this loop use the same `do while` loop

Comment: but the problem is not there ... is in for loop which loops one time instead of m

Comment: same problem in for loop also ... now I edited see my answer now

Comment: I think, You are doing same mistake at two places so I described one.. since the concept is same , so I think you got it didn't you ?

Comment: I made this clear .. in this kind of situation always better to use do-while loop

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize the `B` variabkle, so it loops m times, never asking you to insert a score!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You initialize 'm' here, without any prior value

```
    int m,i,b,sum,min,max,mo;
```

**2.** Without a value, you check for this condition. Which means, a garbage value would be used. (May/May not fulfill your condition)

```
    while (m<1 || m>25) {
```

**3.** The crucial scanf for m is inside the previous while. Without which your FOR would run for a basic i=1 and stop.

```
    for (i=1; i<(m+1); i++) {
```

**You need to understand about Garbage Values in C and vital step of initializing a variable to an initial value before using it.**

You may read more on this link: 
[What is a garbage value/How does it occur in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137239/garbage-values-in-c-c)