# In C if a variable is not assigned a value then why does it take garbage value?

Tags: c, variables, initialization

Why do the variables take garbage values?

Comment: Duplicate of [What happens to a declared, uninitialized variable in C? Does it have a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597405/what-happens-to-a-declared-uninitialized-variable-in-c-does-it-have-a-value), see also: [How an uninitialised variable gets a garbage value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422729/how-an-uninitialised-variable-gets-a-garbage-value)

Comment: More than undetermined, it's *undefined* behavior: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior-in-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unassigned variables has so-called indeterminate state that can be implemented in whatever way, usually by just keeping unchanged whatever data was in memory now occupied by the variable.

Answer (score 7):

I guess the rationale for this is that your program will be faster.

If compiler automatically *reset* (ie: initialize to 0 or to NaN for float/doubles etc etc) your variables, it would take some time doing that (it'd have to write to memory).
In many cases initializing variables could be unneeded: maybe you will never access your variable, or will write on it the first time you access it.

Today this optimization is arguable: the overhead due to initializing variables is maybe not worth the problems caused by variables uninitialized by mistake, but when C has been defined things were different.

Comment: The past tense of "reset" is, I believe, "reset."

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker :( Fixed!

Comment: +1 for mentioning the performance cost / reliability trade-off.

Answer (score 3):

It just takes whatever is in memory at the address the variable is pointing to.

Answer (score 3):

When you allocate a variable you are allocating some memory. if you dont overwrite it, memory will contain whatever "random" information was there before and that is called garbage value.

Comment: Unless it's an extern, which will be automatically initialized to 0, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Soulseekah - Globals and statics.

Answer (score 3):

Why would it **not**? A better question might be "Can you explain how it comes about that a member variable in C# which is **not** initialised has a known default value?"

Comment: @Dervin Thunk: why should any variable have a "default" value? Answer: it doesn't unless something gives it that default value. In C, for instance, static variables are initialised to 0: there is a bit of hidden code which does that, it doesn't happen by magic. So -- I am saying, if you want to see if someone really understands what is happening, ask them why some variables DO have predictable values if they are not (explicitly) initialised.

Answer (score 2):

When variable is declared in C, it involves only assigning memory to variable and no implicit assignment. Thus when you get value from it, it has what is stored in memory cast to your variable datatype. That value we call as garbage value. It remains so, because C language implementations have memory management which does not handle this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This happens with local variables and memory allocated from the heap with malloc().  Local variables are the more typical mishap.  They are stored in the stack frame of the function.  Which is created simply by adjusting the stack pointer by the amount of storage required for the local variables.

The values those variables will have upon entry of the function is essentially random, whatever happened to be stored in those memory locations from a previous function call that happened to use the same stack area.

It is a nasty source of hard to diagnose bugs.  Not in the least because the values aren't really random.  As long as the program has predictable call patterns, it is likely that the initial value repeats well.  A compiler often has a debug feature that lets it inject code in the preamble of the function that initializes all local variables.  A value that's likely to produce bizarre calculation results or a protected mode access violation.

Notable perhaps as well is that managed environments initialize local variables automatically.  That isn't done to help the programmer fall into the pit of success, it's done because not initializing them is a security hazard.  It lets code that runs in a sandbox access memory that was written by privileged code.

Comment: Many good points.  Re "managed environments" (isn't that a terribly MS-centric terminology?), the security issue often makes it essential, but that doesn't imply they're not wanting to help the programmer too - the "philosophy" of Java and .Net is typically to choose tolerance for or prevention of programmer error over CPU- or space-efficiency anyway....