# My project crashes when trying to use doubly indirected pointers (char **)

Tags: c, arrays, double-pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 8

void func (char* ch,char **c1_a,char **c2_a,int* c1_s,int* c2_s)
{
    char* c2_a;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        if(ch[i] >= 'A' && ch[i] <= 'Z')
            (*c1_s)++;
    }
    *c2_s = N - *c1_s;
    *c1_a = (char*)malloc((*c1_s)*sizeof(char));
    *c2_a = (char*)malloc((*c2_s)*sizeof(char));

    *c1_s=*c2_s=0;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        if(ch[i] >= 'A' && ch[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            (**c1_a)[c1_s] = ch[i];
            (*c1_s)++;
        }
        else
        {
            (**c2_a)[c2_s] = ch[i];
            (*c2_s)++;
        }
    }

}

void main ()
{
    char ch[N] = {'A','c','Z','D','G','h','i','Q'};
    char* c1_a,*c2_a;
    int c1_s, c2_s,i;

    func(ch,&c1_a,&c2_a,&c1_s,&c2_s);

    printf("Address for Capital is %d and letters are:\n",c1_a);
    for(i=0;i<c1_s;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",c1_a[i]);
    }
        printf("Address for Small is %d and letters are:\n",c2_a);
    for(i=0;i<c2_s;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",c2_a[i]);
    }



}
```

I checked with F11 and it says it crashes once I get to the line:

```
*c1_a = (char*)malloc((*c1_s)*sizeof(char));
```

I have a project with the same idea only with numbers instead and somehow it works.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: You have redefined the variable c2_a in t the first line of the function func. It is already defined as parameter.

Comment: `(**c1_a)[c1_s]` What do you think this line of code does, and what do you think it is supposed to do? It is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

In both main and in your function, you do not initialize your variables. Because they are automatic variables, they can have any value:

In main:

```
char* c1_a,*c2_a;
int c1_s, c2_s,i;

func(ch,&c1_a,&c2_a,&c1_s,&c2_s);
```

In func:

```
*c2_s = N - *c1_s;
*c1_a = (char*)malloc((*c1_s)*sizeof(char));
*c2_a = (char*)malloc((*c2_s)*sizeof(char));
```

For example, in main `c1_s` isn't initialized so in func `*c1_s` has a random value, etc...

I also note that in func you have a local variable `char* c2_a`. This will override the parameter with the same name in the function heading.

Comment: The `char *c2_a`-thing straight up won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

1. I am surprised that you were able to compile the code that you have shown here. You should have got a redeclaration error for `c2_a` here (below). Anyway, remove that redeclaration.

   ```
   void func (char* ch,char **c1_a,char **c2_a,int* c1_s,int* c2_s)
   {
       char* c2_a;
   ```

   *And just to satisfy my curiosity could you mention the compiler that you are using and the arguments that you are passing to the compiler in the comments.*
2. Initialize c1_s and c2_s. Right now you are working with `random numbers` i.e. [garbage values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422729/how-an-uninitialised-variable-gets-a-garbage-value).

   ```
   int c1_s = 0, c2_s = 0;
   ```
3. Now coming to the most fascinating part of your code -

   ```
    (**c1_a)[c1_s] = ch[i];
   ```

   That this piece of code not only compiles but runs without throwing an exception shows the weakness (or beauty, if that is how you see it) of C.

   What you intended was -

   ```
    (*c1_a)[*c1_s] = ch[i];
   ```

   By amazing coincidence you make 2 mistakes which cancel each other (by that I mean the error combo passes compilation, but it nevertheless fails to give the desired output).
   Your earlier code is equivalent to -

   ```
   char ch;
   int arr[SIZE];

   ch[arr] = 'w'; /* (**c1_a) is a 'char', c1_s is a pointer to an integer */
   ```

   See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/with-c-arrays-why-is-it-the-case-that-a5-5a) to find why your code works in spite of the errors.

Fix these issues and your code will work as expected.

Comment: thanks all ! 
@work.bin
how can i Check what kind of Compiler i got ? 
Plus, didnt really understand the last thing you said about 2 errors canceling each other, it does give the desired output. why wouldnt it?
i just got c1_s and c2_s by reference.

Comment: You wrote `(**c1_a)[c1_s] = ch[i];` but what you need is `(*c1_a)[*c1_s] = ch[i];`. (Look closely at the asterisks).

Comment: Regarding the compiler - how are you compiling your code? Are you using some IDE?

Comment: cool i got what you meant , thanks ! 
i use Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express , tried to install a newer one once but didnt work well.

Comment: I am surprised that VC++ didn't catch the re-declaration error! Anyway, I hope that you finally got your code working as per intent.