# What does struct object represents?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;



struct  A{

   int a;
   int s;
};
int main()
{
    A *S =new A();
    A  obj1=S[0];
    printf(" 0x%x",obj1);
}
```

My question is when i see the out put it seems be 0x0;
and is some cases it becomes 0xFFFFFFFF

can someone explain?

Comment: This is obviously not C. Why is a C tag required?

Comment: This is UB, anything can happen.

Comment: why anything can happen?

Comment: Isn't it also UB if you use `printf` without including `cstdio`? You seem to have a schoolboy habit of writing those first two lines by default.

Comment: @DeiDei That's not "undefined behaviour", but a reason for a compiler error. ... As you can see here, iostream is allowed to include cstdio itself too, so it works in this case.

Comment: @deviantfan: "is allowed" does not imply it has to. The code might work by chance, but that is no way something one should rely on.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, that's why I wrote "is allowed". It is not guaranteed to compile.

Comment: @deviantfan: You should have emphasised the "don't rely on it" part. As you commented, a beginner could get the impression if it works it is fine like it is. Which it is certainly not.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so is wrong (because what you pass to `printf` does not match the `" 0x%x"` format control string, since it has the wrong type); see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

Read [Lattner's blog on undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) (it also applies to C++)

Notice that `printf` is a C library function (so you need to [`#include <cstdio>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c)). In genuine C++11, you would use some [`operator <<` on `std::ostream`-s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2), probably like

```
std::cout << obj1 << std::endl;
```

and that line won't compile (unless you define such an operator, which you should do).

To explain the actual behavior (which is non reproducible in general), you need to dive into implementation details (and you don't want to: if you did, study the source and object code of your particular program and C++ library, of your compiler, of your operating system, look into calling conventions, instruction set, ABIs, etc...). The displayed [garbage value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1422729/841108) (e.g. 0xfffffff) is what happens to sit in some relevant [processor register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) or memory location (on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)).

BTW, if you compiled with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) you'll get a warning. I strongly recommend to enable all warnings.

Notice that a `struct A{` is the same as `class A{public:` so you could define some explicit constructor (which would initialize the fields) and some output `operator<<`:

```
struct  A{
   int a;
   int s;
   A(int aa=0, int ss=0) : a(aa), s(ss) {};
};
std::ostream operator << (std::ostream&out, A a) { 
   out << "a=" << a << ",s=" << s;
   return out;
}
```

But you probably should read about the [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) notably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4782757/841108).

Comment: i understand your part. As i cannot do cout<<obj1.

Comment: What does that values depicts? 0x0 and 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: @Mukesh The second reason is that you have undefined variables. ... Your values are numbers in their hexadecimal form (0 and 4294967295 (or -1 in two's complement)). You should know that already when using %x

Comment: @deviantfan will you elaborate more?

Comment: @Mukesh About what? If you don't understand what a number is, I can't help you.

Comment: i mean those numbers are values for what? and why do they change?

Comment: For whatever the location or processor registers involved contained. You don't want to understand more (and if you do want, work for many years understanding the details of your compiler, your system libraries, your operating system)

Comment: @Mukesh This will be my last comment for now: I told you twice already. If you don't understand it, start googling and/or reading books. (Sigh.)

Comment: if i do like this

Comment: int main()
{
    A *S =new A();
    S->a=5                                                                                                            
    A  obj1=S[0];
    printf(" 0x%x",obj1);
}                                                                                                                                        the output i see is 0x5

Comment: @Mukesh That is because you set it to be 5.  When you do `A *S =new A();` the members of `S`, and subsequently `obj1`, **can be any value**.  There is no requirement for them to be any specific value and the value they have can change from run to run because it is **undefined behavior** (ie, there is no expected behavior from your code).

Comment: How to provide a proper behaviour?

Comment: You can't. You need to initialize your values.

Comment: @Mukesh You write a constructor to properly initialize the values.